# Automatically Add Data into WebSite when Email is received

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am building an Asp.net application where I have a requirement that when an email is send to a particular email account i.e. Help@ourcompany.com, it should automatically insert data into one of my SQL Server table by reading the content in the mail.

Can any one suggest a kick start approach ?

Comment: This seems like the question you want to be asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748079/looking-for-a-real-time-imap-notification-of-new-emails

Comment: or just check the mailbox every x min

Comment: @deebo Thanks. It seems that you pointed me to right direction.

Comment: @Steve I wanted to avoid that overhead on my system. IMAP IDLE seems to be correct approach. I will work more on that and update here. Thanks.

Comment: @deebo , Steve Thanks for your help. I wrote a blog post about this you can find the link in answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use s22.imap library to get instant notifications in my application. you can find the detailed blog post [here](https://dotnetsachin.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/get-new-email-notification-in-net-application-using-imap-idle/) with working code snippet.

Hope this will help some one in need.